# Is Javamail asynchronous or synchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, jakarta-mail, synchronous

Is Javamail asynchronous or synchronous?  That is, if I send off an email, do I continue processing immediately afterwards, or do I wait until it's complete?

Furthermore, are there any ways that I could catch that an email failed to be delivered for any reason?

I'd also like to know these answers for Spring's MailSender abstraction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is synchronous, since it transfers the message to the server and processes the server's response before returning.  The [`send`](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Transport.html#send%28javax.mail.Message%29) docs explain in further detail.  The message will throw a [`SendFailedException`](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/SendFailedException.html), or another [`MessagingException`](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/MessagingException.html),
 if the send fails immediately.  But "success does not imply that the message was delivered to the ultimate recipient, as failures may occur in later stages of delivery."